# Pyspark regexp_replace with list elements are not replacing the string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm tring to replace the string in a dataframe column using regexp_replace. I have to apply regex patterns to all the records in the dataframe column.
But the strings are not replacing as expected.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import sql
from  pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace,col
import re

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstApp").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)


df=sc.parallelize([('2345','ADVANCED by John'),
('2398','ADVANCED by ADVANCE'),
('2328','Verified by somerandomtext'),
('3983','Double Checked by Marsha')]).toDF(['ID', "Notes"])

reg_patterns=["ADVANCED|ADVANCE/ADV/","ASSOCS|AS|ASSOCIATES/ASSOC/"]

for i in range(len(reg_patterns)):
        res_split=re.findall(r"[^/]+",reg_patterns[i])
        res_split[0]
        df=df.withColumn('NotesUPD',regexp_replace(col('Notes'),res_split[0],res_split[1]))

df.show()
```

Output :

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|  ID|               Notes|            NotesUPD|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|2345|    ADVANCED by John|    ADVANCED by John|
|2398| ADVANCED by ADVANCE| ADVANCED by ADVANCE|
|2328|Verified by somer...|Verified by somer...|
|3983|Double Checked by...|Double Checked by...|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+

Expected Output:

+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|  ID|               Notes|            NotesUPD|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|2345|    ADVANCED by John|    ADV by John|
|2398| ADVANCED by ADVANCE|    ADV by ADV |
|2328|Verified by somer...|Verified by somer...|
|3983|Double Checked by...|Double Checked by...|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write a `udf` function and loop in your `reg_patterns` as below

```
reg_patterns=["ADVANCED|ADVANCE/ADV/","ASSOCS|AS|ASSOCIATES/ASSOC/"]

import re
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
def replaceUdf(column):
    res_split=[]
    for i in range(len(reg_patterns)):
        res_split=re.findall(r"[^/]+",reg_patterns[i])
        for x in res_split[0].split("|"):
            column = column.replace(x,res_split[1])
    return column

reg_replaceUdf = f.udf(replaceUdf, t.StringType())

df = df.withColumn('NotesUPD', reg_replaceUdf(f.col('Notes')))
df.show()
```

and you should have

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|  ID|               Notes|            NotesUPD|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|2345|    ADVANCED by John|         ADV by John|
|2398| ADVANCED by ADVANCE|          ADV by ADV|
|2328|Verified by somer...|Verified by somer...|
|3983|Double Checked by...|Double Checked by...|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: glad that it was helpful

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you code repeatedly overwrites previous results starting from the beginning. Instead you should build on the previous results:

```
notes_upd = col('Notes')

for i in range(len(reg_patterns)):
    res_split=re.findall(r"[^/]+",reg_patterns[i])
    res_split[0]
    notes_upd = regexp_replace(notes_upd, res_split[0],res_split[1])
```

and you'll get the desired result:

```
df.withColumn('NotesUPD', notes_upd).show()

# +----+--------------------+--------------------+
# |  ID|               Notes|            NotesUPD|
# +----+--------------------+--------------------+
# |2345|    ADVANCED by John|         ADV by John|
# |2398| ADVANCED by ADVANCE|          ADV by ADV|
# |2328|Verified by somer...|Verified by somer...|
# |3983|Double Checked by...|Double Checked by...|
# +----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: @marjun, this method is preferred over using a udf. You had a simple mistake in your original code, which this answer fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Previous solutions are limited to short length reg_patterns. The below implementation scales nicely when the normalization pattern has many entries (e.g. spell correction using a custom dictionary).

Start by mapping the reg_patterns list to a dictionary:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf

def parse_string(s, or_delim, target_delim):
    keys,value = s.rstrip(target_delim).rsplit(target_delim)
    return {key:value for key in keys.split(or_delim)}

reg_patterns=["ADVANCED|ADVANCE/ADV/","ASSOCS|AS|ASSOCIATES/ASSOC/"]

normalization_dict = {}
for item in reg_patterns:
    normalization_dict.update(parse_string(item, "|", "/"))
```

Complete the normalization of the DataFrame "Notes" column using a curried function as follows:

```
def my_norm_func(s, ngram_dict, pattern):
    return pattern.sub(lambda x: ngram_dict[x.group()], s)

norm_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join([re.escape(item)\
                      for item in normalization_dict.keys()]) + r')\b')
my_norm_udf = udf(lambda s: my_norm_func(s, normalization_dict, norm_pattern))
df = df.withColumn("NotesUPD", my_norm_udf(col("Notes")))
```

yields the following desired result:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|  ID|               Notes|            NotesUPD|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|2345|    ADVANCED by John|         ADV by John|
|2398| ADVANCED by ADVANCE|          ADV by ADV|
|2328|Verified by somer...|Verified by somer...|
|3983|Double Checked by...|Double Checked by...|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
```